# I want to delete a set of numbers from another set of numbers and print the result

Tags: python, sqlite

ListA https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YwE4wRtua7KTdX9IaRoXo8nRyvueIwzSA0IThJULj1s/edit?usp=sharing

List B
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-e-fgCQOIG5PMjCp73GO4OcwvKpBuxKTDeH6UCna1fI/edit?usp=sharing

I want to delete List B elements from List A and print the result. How can I do this?

I have tried with python script but it is just giving out either List A or List B as an Output:

```
import os

with open('/Users/xyz/Desktop/listA.csv') as listA:
        first = listA.read().splitlines()

    with open('/Users/xyz/Desktop/listB.csv') as listB:
        second = listB.read().splitlines()

    bigb = set(first)  - set(second)

    with open('f1.csv', 'w') as f3:
        out = '\n'.join(list(bigb))
        f3.write(out)
```

I also tried with SQLite:

```
SELECT B
FROM listB b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM listA a
    WHERE a.A = b.B)
```

I am struggling hard for this one spent whole day but still not able to solve this problem.

Comment: It would be interesting to see your 2 csv files. When I look at your ListB spreadsheet, I notice that the values in column A are text whereas the same column in ListA is numeric. Thus your two lists (first & second) may contain different types of data which would mean that bigb will only ever contain the values from 'first'

Comment: The data in `listA.csv` is numeric and the data in `listB.csv` is not. So your set difference expression will always equal the left hand operand.

Comment: is it data because it has a double comma?

Comment: No, it's not data because of that. But it does mean that the data in `listA` is different from the data in `listB`. It might be that you think `70000` should be considered equal to `70000"`, but Python doesn't, so you will have to strip off the trailing `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded your lists and corrected 2 issues:

1. listA had an empty row (104), which I removed
2. listB had quotes, which I removed

Then I copied your code and corrected its indentation issues.
After that it worked right away even with numbers represented as strings.
Only the result was unsorted.

Sizes/entries of the sets (with empty line removed):

```
len(listA) = 347675
len(listB) =  16604
len(bigp)  = 331071
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.

Since you need to delete something from listA, you need to start with it's name

```
delete from listA as a
 where exists (select 1 from listB b where b.num_col = a.num_col);
```

UPD. It appeared many of numbers in the listB contain trailing double-quote which need to be removed. I see two ways

```
1. Update table to get rid of double-quotes at all

update listB
   set num_col = replace(num_col, '"','');

then run the script from above

2. If updating table can't be done, you may use this updated query

 delete from listA as a
 where exists (select 1 from listB b where replace(b.num_col, '"', '') = cast(a.num_col as text));
```

Comment: Getting this as an output -- Result: query executed successfully. Took 414194ms, 0 rows affected

Comment: Probably it's because listB contains numbers with double-quotes in the end. I thought that was a mistake

Comment: do you how can I remove it?

Comment: @DaveMustaine please check my updated answer again as I forgot to cast num_col to text in order for correct comparison

Comment: Now listB has single quote at the end like this :  70000'

Comment: @DaveMustaine I assume you've used 4 quotes instead of 2. You did something like that " replace(num_col, '"','''') ", right? Can you rollback changes?

Comment: I removed it now it says this                                                                                   Result: query executed successfully. Took 214133ms, 16603 rows affected

Comment: @DaveMustaine if you were performing delete statement, it means 16603 rows were deleted

Answer (score 0):

You could also use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

def sheet_operation():
    dfListA = pd.read_excel(pathA,sheet_name = 'listA')
    dfListB = pd.read_excel(pathB,sheet_name = 'listB')
    
    result = dfListA - dfListB
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this is a overfit but I usually do these kind of jobs using Pandas. First you can read the file as a dataframe and remove the ListB elements from ListA.

Check out this snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
ListA = pd.read_csv('/Users/xyz/Desktop/listA.csv')
ListB = pd.read_csv('/Users/xyz/Desktop/listB.csv')
List = ListA - ListB
List.write_csv('f1.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check my solution for your task

```
import os

with open('/Users/xyz/Desktop/listA.csv') as listA:
        main_list_A = listA.readlines()

with open('/Users/xyz/Desktop/listB.csv') as listB:
    should_be_deleted_B = listB.readlines()

    main_list_A = [el.replace("\n", "") for el in main_list_A]
    should_be_deleted_B = [el.replace("''\n", "") for el in should_be_deleted_B]

    cleaned_list = set(main_list_A) - set(should_be_deleted_B)  # you can write this list as you do before
```

the main problem that values in your files has different formating, and I just replace useless part for list A it was `"\n"`, for list B `"''\n"`

Comment: Just giving me list B as a result

Comment: no it works, I tested locally.
please check again.


or share your in comments I will review